# How to fix my do while loop in order to have the menu appear again and again until the user presses Letter 'Q'?

Tags: java

Here's my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
// I want to call the menu function in my driver class and in a do while loop . 

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        do {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            char choice = scanner.next().charAt(0);

        } while (choice == 'Q');// How to exit the menue

    }

    static void createNewEmployee() {
        System.out.println("What is the name of employee?");

    }

    static void process() {
        char choice;
        switch (choice) {

        case 'N':
            System.out.println("new employee");
            createNewEmployee();
            break;
        case 'P':
            System.out.println("Compute paychecks");
            break;
        case 'R':
            System.out.println("Raise Wages ");
            break;
        case 'L':
            System.out.println("List Employees ");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Error");

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `while (choice == 'q')` into `while (choice != 'q')`. Think of it like "if the user presses anything apart from 'q', carry on".

Comment: No the problem is with how to take user input again and again !

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you!!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char choice;
    do {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in) ; 
        System.out.print("Press Any Key: N -- New, P -- Paycheck, R -- Raise Wages,-- List Employee, Q -- Quit: ");
        choice = scanner.next().charAt(0);
        process(choice);
    } while(choice !='Q');
}


static void process(char choice) {
    switch (choice) {
    case 'N':
        System.out.println("new employee");
        break;
    case 'P':
        System.out.println("Compute paychecks");
        break;
    case 'R':
        System.out.println("Raise Wages ");
        break;
    case 'L':
        System.out.println("List Employees ");
        break;
    case 'Q':
        System.out.println("Thanks!!");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to create a new `Scanner` on every loop iteration. Also, a `Scanner` object should be closed after you have finished using it, i.e. call method `close()` of class `Scanner`.

Comment: Yes Abra that will make code more optimal. Thanks!!